# Why cannot fetch data from API using apikey

Tags: javascript, reactjs, fetch-api, api-key, themoviedb-api

```
import React, { Component } from "react";
import Nav from "./Nav";
import SearchArea from "./SearchArea";
import MovieList from "./MovieList";

class App extends Component {
  constructor() {
    super();
    this.state = {
      movies: [],
      searchTerm: "",
    };
    this.apiKey = process.env.REACT_APP_API;
  }

  handleSubmit = (e) => {
    e.preventDeafault();

    fetch(
      `https://api.themoviedb.org/3/search/movie?api_key=${this.apiKey}&query=${this.state.searchTerm}`
    )
      .then((data) => data.json())
      .then((data) => {
        console.log(data);
        this.setState({ movies: [...data.results] });
      });
  };

  handleChange = (e) => {
    this.setState({ searchTerm: e.target.value });
  };

  render() {
    return (
      <div className="App">
        <Nav />
        <SearchArea
          handleSubmit={this.handleSubmit}
          handleChange={this.handleChange}
        />
        <MovieList movies={this.state.movies} />
      </div>
    );
  }
}

export default App;
```

I try to make search from movie API and when I start typing on the search the `console.log`didn't appear any data. I have already created .env file.
When I enter the value from my search box, on the console its just refresh I don't know how

```
REACT_APP_API=someapicodehere
```

Comment: It seems that your problem is that the page is being redirected. It's possible that the console shows the result, but you never see it, because the page is redirected prior to that.

Comment: @LajosArpad can you help me to solve this ?

Comment: It should be `e.preventDefault();` (spelling mistake)

Comment: Ajeet Shah is right. e.preventDefault() would prevent the default behavior which is form submission. However, since you call preventDeafault() (notice the extra 'a' in the word), the function you defined crashes and the form is submitted, redirecting the page.